# Viewpager in Dialog?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, view

I'm trying to have a dialog where you can click a "next" button to swipe right to the next screen. I am doing that with a ViewPager and adapter:

```
  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.voicedialog);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        MyPageAdapter adapter = new MyPageAdapter();
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

However, I get a NullPointerException saying that `pager` is null. Why is this happening? Here is the Page Adapter class:

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {

        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.id.voice1;
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = R.id.voice2;
                break;
        }
        return collection.findViewById(resId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == arg1;
    }
}
```

Here's my layout for the DIALOG:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Let me know on how to avoid this situation.

PS: Each of the layouts that should be in the view pager look like this, just diff. text:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/voice2"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <TextView
            android:text="Slide 1!"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout xml

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Done, I have edited the question

Comment: You should call `findViewById` on dialog. Not on current activity.

Comment: I think you are trying to bind your ViewPager before dialog created. You should bind it after dialog's onCreate() method.

Answer (score 9):

### Without Using Enum Class

You should call findViewById on dialog. so for that you have to add dialog before findViewById..

Like this,

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) dialog.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
```

After solving your null pointer exception the other problem's solution here, if you wont use enum class you can use below code...

MainActivity.java

```
package demo.com.pager;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.voicedialog);
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

                MyPageAdapter adapter = new MyPageAdapter(MainActivity.this);
                ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) dialog.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                pager.setAdapter(adapter);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="demo.com.pager.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MyPageAdapter.java

```
package demo.com.pager;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by rucha on 26/12/16.
 */

public class MyPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    int resId = 0;

    public MyPageAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }


    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {

      /*  int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.id.voice1;
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = R.id.voice2;
                break;
        }

        return collection.findViewById(resId);*/

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.layout.fragment_blue;
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = R.layout.fragment_pink;
                break;
        }
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(resId, collection, false);
        collection.addView(layout);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == arg1;
    }
}
```

FragmentBlue.java

```
package demo.com.pager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class FragmentBlue extends Fragment  {

    private static final String TAG = FragmentBlue.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blue, container, false);
        return view;
    }


}
```

fragment_blue.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#4ECDC4">

</RelativeLayout>
```

voicedialog.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please check and reply.

Comment: Okay, I did that, but now the dialog is just an empty screen with no contents or swiping...None of the layouts (voice1 or voice2) are even showing.

Comment: Where did you inflate your layout ?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia i updated the answer check the answer and modify according to your code if any doubt ask again and if you like my ans plz upvoted and accept. Thank you.

Comment: @RuchaBhatt Instead of posting another answer . you must be edited your first answer ! Otherwise moderator or other users will be downvoted to your answer !

Comment: I had to replace `MyPageAdapter(MainActivity.this);` by `MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());`

Comment: @MacaronLover sorry it's way back long and right now not working on this.
but I will try later

Answer (score 0):

### Using Enum Class

Try this code, This is working if any doubt ask again. Happy to help.

MainActivity.java

```
package demo.com.dialogdemo;

import android.app.Dialog; import android.graphics.Color; import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable; import android.os.Bundle; import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager; import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.view.View; import android.view.Window; import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setupUIComponents();
        setupListeners();
    }

    private void setupUIComponents() {
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

    private void setupListeners() {
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Dialog dialogItemDetails = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialogItemDetails.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialogItemDetails.setContentView(R.layout.dialoglayout);
                dialogItemDetails.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                        new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

                ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) dialogItemDetails.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerItemImages);
                viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this));
                dialogItemDetails.show();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dialog" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ModelObject1.java

```
public enum ModelObject1 {

    RED(R.string.red, R.layout.fragment_one),
    BLUE(R.string.blue, R.layout.fragment_two);

    private int mTitleResId;
    private int mLayoutResId;

    ModelObject1(int titleResId, int layoutResId) {
        mTitleResId = titleResId;
        mLayoutResId = layoutResId;
    }

    public int getTitleResId() {
        return mTitleResId;
    }

    public int getLayoutResId() {
        return mLayoutResId;
    }

}
```

CustomPagerAdapter.java

```
package demo.com.dialogdemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by rucha on 26/12/16.
 */

public class CustomPagerAdapter  extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        ModelObject1 modelObject = ModelObject1.values()[position];
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(modelObject.getLayoutResId(), collection, false);
        collection.addView(layout);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ModelObject1.values().length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        ModelObject1 customPagerEnum = ModelObject1.values()[position];
        return mContext.getString(customPagerEnum.getTitleResId());
    }

}
```

dailoglayout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHeaderTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ITEM IMAGES"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerItemImages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragmentone.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="one"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @RuchirBaronia What problem did u face with this code ?

Comment: @Piyush Rather than the code being troublesome, I wanted to find a way to fix my own instead of just copying another. I also think using Enum is not necessary. Besides for the use of Enum, this is almost the exact same as what I provided in my question. I am just trying to figure out how to reference my layout in `instantiateItem` in `MyPageAdapter` since I think my problem is that I am not calling `collection.addView(layout);`, but I don't know how to get that `layout` object. Do you or @Rucha know?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia enum is not necessary at all , i told you update your question and show us what you did till now.. and ok i get it you want to inflate layout without using enum is that your question?

Comment: Then its as simple as you can check [this](https://inducesmile.com/android/understanding-android-viewpager-and-custom-pageradapter/) @RuchirBaronia